# Как использовать гугл АПИ?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, карты

Как использовать гугл апи, чтобы получить координаты ближайщего пункта, допустим, терминала?
Рассчитать я смогу, а вот получить координаты ближайщего терминала или пусть даже продуктового мгазина не знаю как.
Я как понял, у гугла есть какая-то БД, где точками указанны терминалы, вот как мне получить их?

Возможно такое вообще, или это на грани фантастики?

Comment: @Futurama, посмотрите, слева есть меню разных API: адресов, организаций и т.п. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=ru

Comment: @Lucky_spirit, Спасибо, конечно, но сам факт того, что там есть ограничение на запросы просто убило.

Допустим, у меня есть программа, и эту программу используют 50000 тысяч человек, каждому из них приходит ответ от гугл карты ближайщий магазин.

В итоге что у нас получается, 2500 первых получат ответ, а остальных послать куда подальше? Что за бред с ограничением.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit, Может, тогда простым гугл картой пользоваться, через браузер который. То есть на своем сервере делать запрос, а после отправить координаты на устроство, может, тогда такого мизерного ограничения  не будет, или одно и тоже г?

Comment: @Futurama, если не ошибаюсь, то всё, что выше 2500 запросов, нужно отдельно оплачивать. Таким образом, Google на этом зарабатывает деньги и в этом его нельзя обвинить.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit,  а бесплатно никак?

Comment: а почему это, собственно, должно быть бесплатно? если бы ограничения не было, то нагрузки были бы неимоверные

Comment: @Futurama, просто перенесите запрос к Google API на сторону пользователя. Тогда каждый из 50000 Ваших пользователей смогут сделать по 2500 запросов.